# Kubectl run with replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create a deployment with Kubectl run. I want to specify replicas as part of the command.
I get

```
Error: unknown flag: --replicas
```

Is this deprecated in the current version. If yes how do we achieve replicas.

Comment: Please show what you are doing and describe the cluster setup used.

Comment: Can you share which kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: `kubectl run` create a single pod, not a deployment

Answer (score 2):

Using `kubectl run` for deployments has been deprecated for quite some time and removed in a recent kubernetes version.

If you want to create a deployment using the kubectl commandline, use

```
kubectl create deployment $deploymentname --image $image --replicas $replicacount
```

see the official documentation for [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) for more detail.